# Drag images on website with stylus/pen

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, stylus-pen

I want to write an app based on JavaScript that enables users to drag&drop images on a site into a `<canvas>`. There is a code example [here](https://codepen.io/Prebyter/pen/ggVxWo) and it's working quite well - with a mouse. The same effect doesn't work when I use a stylus or digital pen as an input device. Adding "-webkit-user-drag" property or "draggable" attribute to the image didn't help.

How can I achieve this (I'm using either Chrome or Edge)?

Comment: That is probably first and foremost an issue of _how_ that pen interacts with the browser/OS, as what kind of an input device it registers ... go find that out first.

Comment: Most stylus drivers will allow mouse or touch emulation but the browser has limited control with only pressure and x,y radius. Things like tilt and rotation are not available.

Comment: To clarify: The device is a Surface Book